# Remove styling of : (colon) in Emacs cc-mode?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'd like to remove colon styling, which typically appears like:

```
goto:
```

The code that adds colon styling starts on [line 457](https://github.com/emacsmirror/cc-mode/blob/master/cc-styles.el#L457).

It's not necessary but would be nice if I could remove colon styling only in certain directories like:

- /root/project/hi.c
- /root/project_remove_colon/hi.c

Thanks!

Comment: There's an answer for customizing the face, i.e. the look.  But your link points to the indentation code... do you want to change how that is indented?

Comment: Yes! I'd like to remove all styling, including indentation. I'd like Emacs to treat the colon like an alphanumeric character.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to set `c-label-face-name` as a file local variable. For example, in your file `/root/project_remove_colon/hi.c` you could add the following comment block at the end of the file:

```
/* Local Variables: */
/* c-label-face-name: font-lock-reference-face */
/* End: */
```

An issue with this approach, though, is that `c-label-face-name` is [not considered safe as a file-local variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Safe-File-Variables.html), so when you visit the file, emacs will prompt you like this:

```
The local variables list in hi.c
contains variables that are risky (**).

Do you want to apply it?  You can type
y  -- to apply the local variables list.
n  -- to ignore the local variables list.

** c-label-face-name : font-lock-reference-face
```

To avoid this prompt, you could [customize `safe-local-variable-values`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Local-Variables.html) to mark the variable `c-label-face-name` as being safe.